# How to edit an old GRUB entry to point to a new installation

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, boot, grub

I was using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, but decided to try out Debian 11. 
I created an installation USB, booted from the USB
and installed Debian by wiping the entire drive.

The installer reported no issues and exited normally. 
However, after removing the USB and rebooting,
the computer was not booting to Debian. 
Instead a message said Ubuntu does not exist. 
I was confused why GRUB was still looking for the nonexistent Ubuntu. 
Much to my surprise, the GRUB and Linux kernel that came with Ubuntu
were not replaced by the Debian installer.

I tried installing again but nothing changed. I booted Ubuntu from a live USB
and ran recovery tools, but none of them fixed the issue.

My only option might be to edit the Ubuntu GRUB's boot entry manually so that it points to the new Debian installation. How can I do this?

Comment: For more detail, can you specify the disk structure you have on your system? you can use `sudo fdisk -l` or `lsblk`.

Comment: Check your UEFI entries & ESP partition. Ubuntu uses "ubuntu", but I think Debian uses "grub". `sudo efibootmgr -v` If you can mount ESP (ubuntu makes it difficult), check /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg & /EFI/grub. You probably can just change UUID in /EFI/ubuntu/grub to new installs UUID and also have it work. But UEFI should be defaulting to new install. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198221/cloning-ssd-also-cloned-boot-options/1198228#1198228 Also go into UEFI setting (not menu) and change boot order there. Or was one install UEFI and other now BIOS, or vice-versa?

Answer (score 0):

Everything indicates that during the Debian installation you have failed or skipped in the grub installation itself. It is possible that you have inadvertently installed it on another disk, to give an example of a possible cause.

I consider that the simplest and most scalable way to solve your problem is to reinstall grub by hand, take advantage of the Ubuntu Live image you have and log in to the system.

The first step will be to locate the partitions of the various disks with:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

To continue with the explanation, I'm going to assume that this is `/dev/sda`, but if it had another name, replace it. You must mount the partitions on which you have debian, which will probably be `/dev/sda2` (assuming that `/dev/sda1` is the `/boot` partition):

```
mkdir -p /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
mkdir -p /mnt/boot
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot
```

Now, mount the rest of the devices:

```
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev 
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts 
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc 
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
```

Execute the `chroot` command so that we access the file system of Debian as root:

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

Once caged, we install `grub` on the MBR:

```
grub-install --boot-directory=/boot/ --recheck /dev/sda
```

We restart and when Debian boots up again (not the LiveCD one), we can adjust in the `grub` menu manually editing the configuration if any OS is missing, or do it automatically with the following command:

```
sudo update-grub2
```